# Duplicate php array with keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like so:

```
[day0_units] => 0
[day1_units] => 12
[day1_start] => 08:00:00
[day1_end] => 11:00:00
[day2_units] => 12
[day2_start] => 07:00:00
[day2_end] => 11:00:00
[day3_units] => 0
[day4_units] => 12
[day4_start] => 10:00:00
[day4_end] => 12:00:00
[day5_units] => 12
[day5_start] => 08:00:00
[day5_end] => 03:00:00
[day6_units] => 0

[day0_units] => 0
[day0_start] => 10:00:00
[day0_end] => 01:00:00
[day1_units] => 12
[day1_start] => 08:00:00
[day1_end] => 11:00:00
[day2_units] => 12
[day2_start] => 07:00:00
[day2_end] => 11:00:00
[day3_units] => 0
[day3_start] => 
[day3_end] => 
[day4_units] => 12
[day4_start] => 10:00:00
[day4_end] => 12:00:00
[day5_units] => 12
[day5_start] => 08:00:00
[day5_end] => 03:00:00
[day6_units] => 0
```

All I want to do is duplicate the array keys, both arrays should have the same keys in the same positions and retain the values if any. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unsure if this is the direction you want, but have you looked at [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) by any chance?

Comment: @Mari M: I don't think that will work because some of the values for the array need to stay. A key will be missing and I want to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the keys from both and merge them, then flip and merge with the arrays:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));
$array1 = array_merge($keys, $array1);
$array2 = array_merge($keys, $array2);
```

Comment: Will this keep the keys in the same order? Not sure if array_diff_assoc() even cares about the order so not sure if matters.